# Passing parameters to a Django URL fails

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to have a dummy call for the missing pages in a project so I can keep track of what is missing. A simple "In construction" page with the name of the missing link. Instead of putting the real link i put this in the calling html, vacia.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' pagref='aquisalto' %}"> PuntoDeSalto </a></li>
```

The url is decoded in urls this way:

`href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' pagref=aquisalto %}`"

It should go to incid/xtodo with the parameter "aquisalto"
This is the xtodo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>En construcción</title>
</head>
<h1 align="left">EN CONSTRUCCIÓN</h1>

<h1>
   <h1>{{pagref}}</h1>
<div>
    <img src="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}/static/logos/Under_construction_icon-orange.svg.png" width="300"
         height="250" alt="UnderConstruction"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the xtodo view:

```
def xtodo_view(request):  # para pruebas, quitar
    global pagref
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pagref = request.GET.get('pagref', 'g')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        pagref = request.POST.get('pagref', 'p')
    return render(request, 'incid/xtodo.html', {'pagref': pagref})
```

I do not find a way a form to make it work, and it should be so simple. I am using DJANGO 3 and Python 3.
I have tried other call forms like :

```
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo'?pagref='aquisalto' %}"  
or
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo'%}?pagref='aquisalto'"
```

with and without ? and with and without ' or " .

Definitely I have missed to understand something important in this. I cannot put such a simple thing to work to have todo show with the value of pagref in it. The error I am getting with the current coding is:
TypeError at /incid/xtodo/

**xtodo_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pagref'**

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are passing parameters is not right.

You can do it using 2 ways as below:

> **1. Using `path` parameters**

*views.py*

```
def xtodo_view(request, my_param):  # para pruebas, quitar
    # here my_param will have anything you pass
    return render(request, 'incid/xtodo.html', {'pagref': my_param})
```

*calling this view in url*

```
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' 'g' %}"
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' 'p' %}"
```

In 1st case in your view you will get **`my_param`** as `'g'` and in 2nd case you will get my_param as `'p'`.

> **2. Using `query` parameters**

When you pass query parameters from url like `www.abc.xyz?q1=val1&q2=val2`.
You can get these query parameters `q1` and `q2` using **`request.GET.get(q1)`** and **`request.GET.get(q2)`**.

*views.py*

```
def xtodo_view(request):  # para pruebas, quitar
    pageref = ""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pagref = request.GET.get('pagref', 'g')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        pagref = request.GET.get('pagref', 'p')

    return render(request, 'incid/xtodo.html', {'pagref': pagref})
```

*calling this view in url*

```
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo'}?pagref=abc"  
href="{% url 'incid:xtodo'%}?pagref=xyz"
```

In 1st case using **`request.GET.get('pageref', 'p')`** will give **`'abc'`** and in 2nd case it will give **`'xyz'`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, method two did the trick on first try. My error was keepin the parameter between single quotes and not initializing the pagref value in the view. I had tried so many combinations that I left that out. I still am not fluent as to when to use which quotes or where.

Comment: @carolvs, you can mark this answer as selected if this helped.

Comment: Did it. It was of great help. Thanks.